# Fresco consumes more memory for image caching?

Tags: android, fresco, image-caching

I am working on one of the chat application where images are getting downloaded.

Recently I switched to Fresco for memory caching. I am not using Fresco to download images However using fresco to view images by creating URI using **already downloaded local file**.

However as per Android profiler, it has been observed that, Fresco is consuming more memory as compare to my old memory caching mechanism.

I have not used more advance customisation & simply used **"Fresco.initialize(context)"** for initialisation.

**could you please suggest, where I am making mistake?
Here is my code:**

```
private void setImage(Context context, boolean isSvg, final SimpleDraweeView imageView, final String filePath, ImageData data) {
    GenericDraweeHierarchy hierarchy = GenericDraweeHierarchyBuilder.newInstance(context.getResources()).build();
    if(data.isFadeInBitmap()) {
        hierarchy.setFadeDuration(FADE_IN_TIME);
    }
    if(data.isRound()) {
        hierarchy.setRoundingParams(RoundingParams.asCircle());
    }
    int width = imageView.getLayoutParams().width;
    int height = imageView.getLayoutParams().height;
    ImageRequestBuilder imageRequestBuilder = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(UriUtil.getUriForFile(new File(filePath)));
    if (width > 0 && height > 0) {
        imageRequestBuilder.setResizeOptions(new ResizeOptions(width, height));
    }
    DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
            .setOldController(imageView.getController())
            .setImageRequest(imageRequestBuilder.build())
            .build();
    imageView.setHierarchy(hierarchy);
    imageView.setController(controller);

    if(isSvg) {
        imageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE,null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Image downsampling may help you, but not sure

Comment: I am doing downsampling by calling  
                                                 
                                                 
                                             
:imageRequestBuilder.setResizeOptions(new ResizeOptions(width, height));

Answer (score 0):

Fresco has different memory caches, for encoded and decoded images. You can customize the cache sizes to be similar to your previous applications if you want to do so.
More information on caching can be found here: http://frescolib.org/docs/caching.html

In order to customize the caches, you can pass your own `MemoryCacheParams` to the ImagePipelineConfig for the encoded and bitmap (decoded) cache.

You are resizing the images, which is great. You can also consider enabling downsampling, which might be more performant. Take a look at http://frescolib.org/docs/resizing.html to learn more about which way is better for your app (downsampling vs resizing).